# In repository pattern, should i expose func<T, bool> or have multiple very similar methods?

Tags: c#, repository, repository-pattern

In repository pattern when it comes to defining our methods, it's preferable to have a "generic" method accepting any filter using `Func<T, bool>`, or to have many descriptive methods for each filter?

### Generalistic way

```
public User Get(Func<User, bool> filter)
{
    return _context.User.SingleOrDefault(filter);
}

public List<User> GetAll(Func<User, bool> filter)
{
    return _context.User.Where(filter).ToList();
}
```

---

### One method for parameter way

```
public User GetByEmail(string email)
{
    return _context.User.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Email == email);
}

public User GetByPostalCode(string postalCode)
{
    return _context.User.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Address.PostalCode == postalCode);
}
```

Comment: Absolutely, without a doubt, go with the first option.

Comment: @ZoharPeled But in this way, in the service layer you are going to have more specific methods or it's ok to filter by Func<T, bool> in controller?

Comment: I would keep the methods as general as possible until there is actually a need to be specific. You should not repeat code just to be specific. The function you pass shouls be readable enough so you can use only general methods.

Answer (score 1):

I use the fist option and additionally define methods that return `Expression<Func<User, bool>>` that can be passed as parameters.

```
public Expression<Func<User, bool>> GetAdults()
{
    return user => user.Age >= 18;

}
```

Comment: But in this way, in the service layer you are going to have more specific methods or it's ok to filter by Func<T, bool> in controller?

Comment: I keep my business logic out of the controller and put that in a business object or service. In this example I'm using a pseudo query object pattern.